# scp file from Kubernetes cluster to external server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

All Kubernetes documentation I've seen around copying files is using 'kubectl cp' command.
https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/container_debugging/copying_container_files.html

Is there a way to copy a file from a POD to an external server outside of the cluster that isnt using kubectl?

If I an able to exec onto the POD do I need to open a nodeport to scp the file externally?

Answer (score 1):

No need to open any ports to make egress TCP connection. Just `scp`. If a pod has access to that server (egress firewall/egress security groups) - it will just work.

Exec+scp is the easiest option, mind that you should have ssh key inside the pod, or know the password of a target server. Otherwise, you might upload files to S3, etc.

Comment: What about the reverse? Is it possible to scp from an external server directly into the pod without using an intermediately?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, you do need to open NodePort and point it to the ssh server inside the pod.

Comment: Cheers. Just trying to get my head around this one. Doesn't the POD have only a internal IP? Does the destination have to be some sort of nested address using the node IP with the node port and then the pod IP?

Comment: Correct, node_ip:node_port. Any manual about exposing a TCP server in k8s will work for you.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

Comment: Also, I have found that exec+scp works using the external server as the source and the pod as the destination. For some reason, I always thought the source had to be local to where scp was run from...

Comment: And, wouldn't you know, the *namespace* is **not** specified with the `-n` option, and no-one mentions that. You'll probably get `pod not found` unless you include the namespace like a path prefix to the pod name, and, hold on again, because you *don't* specify the pod name with the `pod/` prefix like you might normally do, and no-one mentions that either: `$ kubectl cp /path/to/file $namespace/$pod:/path/to/file -c $container`

Comment: If you've got yourself the `$pod` variable in your environment naming your target pod, like you used something like `$ pod=$(kubectl get pods -o name | grep the-pod | head -1)` then you'll have a very useable pod name like `pod/the-pod-123456` which can be given to `kc get` or `kc describe` without any fuss, but you can convert to drop the prefix like this `$ pod=${pod:4:99}`.